# mysql - Select with "if" preference

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to load 50 entires with preference.
let's assume i have

```
User_id  mid     preference
564      djng    2
123      e3r3    1
423      u5h5    1
544      djnw    2
545      njdw    2
```

The thing is to load firstly the entires with perference "1" and if there is no "1" then load all other left, with limit 50, so when we have 40 entires with preference "1" and for instance 100 with preference "2" so mysql query gets
first 40 entires with preference "1" and then append left 10 with preference "2"

Currently i have

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM $db1 WHERE userid!='$userid' AND mediaid NOT IN 
           (SELECT mid FROM $db2 WHERE uid='$userid')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems to have little to do with what you're asking, but the general way of doing this is to use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY preference
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Comment: usage order by is , simply ORDER BY 1 for firstly "1" i guess ?

Comment: ORDER BY preference, use the column name

Comment: no, `ORDER BY 1` will order by the first output column. `ORDER BY Preference` will order by the preference column, meaning that preference 1 will be on top. So if you have 40 rows with preference 1 and 100 rows with preference 2, you'll get all preference 1 and 10 preference 2, thanks to the LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $db1 WHERE userid!='$userid' AND mediaid NOT IN (SELECT mid FROM $db2 WHERE uid='$userid') ORDER BY preference ASC LIMIT 50";
```

Comment: Though your answer may be correct, please explain with a reference why and how this works.